# JPA criteriabuilder group by 1

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to migrate my postgres native querys to use criteriabuilder instead.

What I want to achieve is:
select date_trunc('day',t.starttime) AS day, count(*) AS no_of_users from login_table t group by 1 order by 1

So far I I don't see how to build the group by 1 order by 1.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<RequestPerWeek> cq = cb.createQuery(RequestPerWeek.class);
    Root<TLogin> from = cq.from(TLogin.class);
    String date = "week";
    Expression<Calendar> dateTrunc=cb.function("date_trunc",Calendar.class,cb.literal(date), from.get(TLogin_.starttime).as(Calendar.class));
    cq.select(cb.construct(RequestPerWeek.class,cb.count(from),dateTrunc));
```

I've tried several groupby alternatives, but noone works like I want it to :-|

best regards,
hw

Answer (score -1):

We are using spring data jpa in our project and if you use it, there is no need to write criteria query for simple queries, you can simply write the query directly on top of your method and get the result. This approach is 'Using named parameters'

For example,

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :firstname or u.lastname = :lastname")
  User findByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastname") String lastname,
                                 @Param("firstname") String firstname);
}
```

Below link is useful for anyone who is using spring data jpa, if you are writing criteria query take a look if you can get your result using named parameters approach. This is simple and you write very less code.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.named-parameters